# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require

I'm using a JS library wrapper for guerrilla mail api. It's written for ES6 so the it use the `import` to load dependencies. Since I need to require it inside a cli node script, I get this error when I try to require it:

```
/Users/dev/Desktop/guerrillamail-cli/node_modules/guerrillamail-api/src/index.js:1
import axios from 'axios';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Is there any way to use the library? I'm thinking to replace all the import with require but not sure if this exploit will work. Any suggestion about?